# Separate Fraction or not in Equation

Tags: equations

I want to write the equation for hyperbolic sinh in my document. But I can't find a way which I think looks good. The alternatives I have tried are:

```
\begin{equation} \label{sinh_eq}
\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}}\Bigr)
\end{equation}
```

and:

```
\begin{equation} \label{sinhx_eq}
\frac{e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}}}{2}.
\end{equation}
```

I have been taught that the first alternative is the right way to write this type of equation, but I think it looks quite bad (1/2 looks too big). The second one looks better imo, but is this a correct way of writing it? For other similar equations in my document I use the first alternative so it would be nice to have the same style.

The equations can be visualized [here](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B2%7D%5CBigl(e%5E%7BY_%7Bd,h%7D%7D-e%5E%7BY_%7Bd,h%7D%7D%5CBigr)) and [here.](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?%5Cfrac%7Be%5E%7BY_%7Bd,h%7D%7D-e%5E%7BY_%7Bd,h%7D%7D%7D%7B2%7D)

I am also attaching pictures below.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I see no problem with the second variant in displayed formulas. In inline formulas, the situation is different. [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edkjU.png).

Comment: You shouldn't use `\Big` size in the formula on the left. I wouldn't even use `\big` size. Of course you're forgetting a minus sign, but it's not relevant for the question. The answer is “do as you think fit”.

Comment: Off-topic: There should be a `-` (minus) symbol in the argument of the second exponential expression.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. @egreg how come, how should I think about the parentheses size?

Answer (score 3):

Do alternatives 3 and/or 4 in the following screenshot look better to you than first two alternatives?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align*' env.
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % optional (Palatino clone text and math fonts)

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\sinh (Y_{d,h})
&= \frac{1}{2} \bigl(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{-Y_{d,h}}\bigr) \\ 
&= \frac{e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{-Y_{d,h}}}{2}  \\
&= \bigl(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{-Y_{d,h}}\bigr)\big/2 \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2} \bigl(\exp(Y_{d,h})-\exp(-Y_{d,h})\bigr) 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the over-sized parentheses, but any of these seem OK, depending on your preferences

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

frac 1 2
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}})
\end{equation}

tfac 1 2
\begin{equation}
\tfrac{1}{2}(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}})
\end{equation}

frac
\begin{equation}
\frac{e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}}}{2}
\end{equation}

/
\begin{equation}
(e^{Y_{d,h}}-e^{Y_{d,h}})/2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you. And mixing styles (I use for example `\frac{1}{N_h}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big|P_{d,h} - \hat{P}_{d,h} \Big|` in another Equation in my document. Is not a problem? How come no over-sized parentheses?

Comment: @SimonRydstedt (almost) never use `\Big` always `\Bigr` and `\bigl` as for not using over-sized delimiters, it just looks ugly:-)